# When a web page is loaded I want to change any link in this page

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I mentioned in the title, I'm looking for any script or extension that will be able to do this.

In my country, imgur has been blocked and I don't want to use VPN, I am using 0imgur.com to view any images. But it doesn't work on webpages. So When a webpage is loaded, I want that it changes this URLs automatically. Like this:

- Page loads:
  [image: Page loads]
- And
- If it exits, an extension changes all " imgur.com/{image-id} " urls to " 0imgur.com/{image-id} ":
  [image: If it exits, an extension changes all " imgur.com/{image-id} " urls to " 0imgur.com/{image-id} "]

**I have solved my problem. Thank you for all answers and comments.**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').each(function() {
            var $img = $(this);
            var imgsrc = $img.attr('src');
            var imgalt = $img.attr('alt');
            var newresult = imgsrc.split(".");
            newresult[1] = "0"+newresult[1];
            var finalUrl = newresult.join(".");
            console.log(finalUrl); 
            $img.attr('src',finalUrl);
            $img.attr('alt',imgalt);
        });
    });
```

**I have combined codes what you give in the answers.**

> And I have added this code to my bookmarks as javascript.

```
javascript:(

    <!-- codes -- >
    <!-- codes -- >

)()
```

Comment: Please make an attempt at solving the problem. If you run into issues along the way, post what you have tried as a [mcve].

Comment: https://github.com/CanNuhlar/Imgur-to-0Imgur-Chrome-Browser-Extension this could help you

Comment: Please add some code samples, if you really need help.

Comment: @MarvinFischer it works thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The function below would enable you achieve that

```
let replaceUrl = ()=>{
 let imgElements = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("img"))
 if ( imgElements.length  > 0 ){
   imgElements.each(elem){
     elem.src = elem.src.replace("imgur", "Oimgur")
   }
 }
}
```